# Save CSV File with Phonegap from HTML Table

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, csv

I am developing an Android 4.4.4 app on Phonegap.

I am not allowed to use PHP or any online services, so i have to solve this without user having internet access. This is my first Phonegap project and i am not familiar with most of the things.

Sample table would be something like this:

```
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1_1</td>
        <td>Data 1_2</td> 
        <td>Data 1_3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 2_1</td>
        <td>Data 2_2</td> 
        <td>Data 2_3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<button type="button">Download CSV!</button>
```

And then i want "Download CSV!" button to save the table as a CSV file.

I tried the method here: https://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/kpegu/
It works fine on the browser side, but on phone/tablet it doesn't download anything.

So i am looking for another way to download CSV from Table

Thanks for taking your time to read this.